# Htaccess RewriteRule with parameters throw 404 error

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, html

I've got wordpress website on my localhost in folder "abcd".

Address look like this: localhost/abcd. I would like to redirect `localhost/abcd/xxx/first/second` to `localhost/abcd/xxx?a=first&b=second`.

I wrote this htaccess code, but it isn't correct and page throw 404 error :

```
RewriteRule ^xxx/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ /abcd/xxx?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA]
```

What is wrong?

It's my all .htaccess file:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /abcd/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /abcd/index.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^xxx/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ /abcd/xxx?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA]
  </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an ending slash in your pattern that prevent the matching. Besides, `^` indicates the start of the page name, so either remove it or use `^abcd/...`. The following should work:

`RewriteRule ^abcd/xxx/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ /abcd/xxx?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA]`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it still doesn't work. I've got again 404 error.

Comment: The rule I gave you do match the URL you provided (take a look at [this tool](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/), it can be useful to test your rules beforehand).

Are you sure the destination is valid? Do you really need the `[QSA]` flag?

Comment: Thanks for this tool it's very useful. I think it's problem with wordpress. I'm not sure with [QSA]